# Android. Проверка на регистрацию реального человека(девайса)

Tags: android, безопасность

Есть клиент серверное приложение с регистрацией. Необходимо, чтобы регистрировался реальный человек(девайс), а не скрипт посылал пост запросы на регистрацию. Как можно в этом удостовериться? Вроде, есть у девайса аккаунты. И наверняка возможно проверить как то (например с помощью гугл апи), что девайс и аккаунт соответствуют. Но как это сделать?

P.S. конкретнее надо сделать так, что бы злодей не смог зарегистрировать много(100+) аккаунтов.

Comment: Просить номер паспорта лично выдавать ключи людям)
Но если заморочиться, то можно при регистрации вытягивать какой-нибудь уникальный номер девайса типа MAC-адреса.

Comment: А еще можно почитать вот это - http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id

Comment: oleg_ismaylov, по поводу уникального номера девайса, как сервер проверит, что девайс реальный? Да и на самом деле если даже реальный, их много. Нужно как то проверить связку аккаунт + девайс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте Oauth 2.0 для андроид.
Суть: достаем с девайса аккаунт, генерим для него AccessToken для получения информации о email. И передаем на сервер этот AccessToken и email аккаунта. На сервера по AccessToken запрашиваем у гугла email, и если совпадает с тем, что прислал юзер - можно выдавать свой token, с которым и работать дальше.

1. [Авторизация](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html)
2. [Сама библиотека](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2)
3. [Блогозапись, которая может помочь](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2012/05/oauth2-android.html)

При возникновении других вопросов - просто гуглите: информации достаточно.

Comment: Это дает гарантию, что девайс соответствует аккаунту?(То есть я не могу запросить AccessToken, используя аккаунт другого устройства?)

Comment: Oauth 2.0 вместе с AccessToken  и есть мой второй вариант, просто не хотел грузить человека лишними библиотеками. У него достаточно простая задача....

Comment: Но в первом случае приложение будет работать только если скачать через гугл плей?

Comment: Забудь про девайс. Думайте про аккаунт. Вы должны давать возможность заходить в приложение с 1го девайса под несколькими аккаунтами. Описанным способом вы просто правильно огранизуете авторизацию внутри своего приложения.

Comment: Мне более важно, что бы было невозможно написать скрипт, который будет автоматически регистрировать большое количество псевдо-пользователей. В этом случае разве нельзя взять какой либо аккаунт, который существует на каком нибудь из девайсов, запросить по нему токен и послать серверу, то есть аккаунт то существует такой, но пользователь не настоящий.

Comment: а как вы узнаете на сервере, имея только токен, какому аккаунту он привязан? Вот поэтому и надо использовать Oauth 2.0 !

Comment: Я, используя Oauth,на сервер буду посылать аккаунт  + токен, и буду проверять на сответствие, то есть, буду делать все что вы сказали. Но, разве на клиенте нельзя генерить токен любого аккаунта (существующего на каком нибудь из девайсов)?

Answer (score 2):

Доброй ночи!

Можно привязаться к аккаунту Google Play. Таким образом проверять реальность аккаунта перед запросом на регистрацию. Минусом такого подхода - установка только через гугл плей.

Второй вариант:  перед разрешением любых запросов проводить идентификацию устройства. Самый простой способ, сгенерировать ХЭШ ключ (передав его на сервер вместе с инфой о девайсе единственным разрешенным без него методом АПИ), и сохранить его в SharedPreferences софта, передавать в дальнейшем при каждом запросе к серваку.

Это самые простые два варианта, которые на вскидку приходят в голову

Comment: По поводу привязки к Google Play. 
Вы про это? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html . Нельзя ли тогда ввести любую почту из гугл плея? Или, когда я запрашиваю токен у гугл плея через андроид, проверяется на сответствие аккаунт и девайс?
По поводу второго варианата. 
Тут же можно передать при регистрации передать вместо хэша что угодно, разве нет? И затем, пользоваться этим хэшом.

Comment: По гугл плей, да, я имел ввиду именно это. Гугл плей проверяет привязку утсройства к учетной записи (ибо он показывает на каком устройстве какой софт). Еще раз обращу внимание что в таком случае ваш апп будет жестко привязан к гугл плей.

По второму варианту с ХЭШ ключем - хеш ключ должен генерироваться на основе данных устройства к примеру IMEI + хэш. И при первой регистрации хеш кода, необходимо передать данные однозначно идентифицирующие устройство (IMEI, UID, GSM  сеть и что вашей душе угодно)

Comment: У обоих вариантов проблемы: 1) Чтобы использовать 1 девайс для двух аккаунтов - придеться перевязывать гугл плей. 2) Вообще отсутвует возможность использования 1го девайса для двух аккаунтов. (даже бонально продали телефон, и ваш акк юзает другой человек, либо он не может привязать свой.)

Comment: Это не страшно для данного приложения. Главное, что бы нельзя было написать скрипт для регистрации 100500 пользователей.

Comment: Если просто доставать аккаунт с телефона - как на сервере вы узнаете, что он валидный? С успехом можно делать фейковые запросы с лапшой вместо имэйла и получите нежеланных юзеров. ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО надо передовать 2 параметра, причем один из них должен иметь время жизни.

Comment: Ответ считаю полностью не правильным, тк в обоих случаях возможно создание любого количества юзеров, тк нет валидации на сереве (нечго валидировать)

Comment: Не согласен, обратите внимание на банковское ПО, оно привязывается к устройству. Поставьте Сбербанк Онлайн, и увидите окошко в которое нужно ввести код привязки апа к устройству. Так же и в других мобильных банках. Привязывается не аккаунт а УСТРОЙСТВО. 
Все зависит от решаемой задачи. Jimpanzer, мы с вами оба правы, просто немного в разных сферах видимо работаем,  и мыслим немного по разному :)

Comment: Главный момент это то, что в вашем ответе нет ни слова про "увидите окошко в которое нужно ввести код привязки апа к устройству". А именно этим они и проводят валидацию. Я хочу сказать, что оба варианта описанные в ответе очень сильно уязвимы. и советовать это, немного некрасиво.

Comment: Почему первый вариант уязвим?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут нет способа, основанного на специфики девайса. Но, на мой взгляд, схема обезопасить себя от массового создания аккаунтов такая:

- На момент авторизации ограничить время выполнения запроса (например не чаще 10 секунд на запрос с одного айпишника)
- Провести взаимо-обмен информацией клиента с сервером на основе набора каких-то случайных правил (и сделать цепочку множественной) например:
- - Клиент отправляет серверу свой уникальный номер (любой, IMEI или всё что угодно)
- - Сервер прибавляет к этому например 10. У сервера и клиента есть параметризованое дерево вопросов и ответов по которому они обмениваются верными ответами и вопросами N раз. Если всё верно - то высока вероятность что клиент - это мобильное приложение.
- Можно ещё придумать вариантов в этом же духе. Тут главное что должна работать связка сервера с клиентом, решая вопрос только на одной стороне не получится. Можно ещё почитать про приватные и публичные ключи и ssl аутентификацию. Не в плане применения технологий, а в плане использовании аналогичных принципов.